# Removing price information and 'Add to Cart' from spree website

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, spree

I am building an e-commerce site using spree. I am new to Ruby/RoR and Spree, though not to programming and web development.

I am still carrying out research on logistics, pricing, which products to actually stock up on etc., so I simply want to display product information, and not the price and/or ability to purchase.

I have searched extensively online (to no avail), on how to do the following things I ave listed below:

I want to know how (perhaps, this requires code modification):

1. NOT show the price of products ANYWHERE on the site (including the product page)
2. On the product page, NOT show the 'Add to Cart' button
3. On the product page, SHOW a form that allows the user to register to the site, so that they can be contacted when the product becomes available

I am not looking for detailed steps, simply guidelines that I can follow to make the appropriate changes to the configuration (or code - if required), in order to meet these requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need to override the view templates.

Try running `bundle show spree` or `bundle open spree` if you have an editor setup for bundle, this way you'll know which file you need to change. Its likely going to be somewhere [here](https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/master/frontend/app/views/spree/products/show.html.erb) or in one of the partials, look around.

Then you can override it with deface, see [Spree Docs here](https://guides.spreecommerce.com/developer/deface_overrides_tutorial.html)

If you want override the whole file, then just create the file in your app, for example, if you wanted to override spree/frontend/app/views/spree/products/show.html.erb from the gem.

You'd create the same file with your custom code in it, make sure to follow the same path and naming.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'll try what you suggested, and see if that helps address the issues I raised.